# How to count the maximum value and make sql display one single row

Tags: t-sql

I am learning SQL and want to make the following:
I need to get the highest value from 2 different tables. OUTPUT Displays all rows, however I need a single row with the maximum value.

P.S. LIMIT 1 is not working in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT Players.PlayersID, MAX (Participants.EventsID) AS Maximum FROM Players
LEFT JOIN Participants ON Players.PlayersID = Participants.PlayersID
GROUP BY Players.PlayersID
```

I clearly understand that this can be a dumb question for pros, however Google did not help. Thanks for understanding and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    pl.PlayersID,
    MAX(pa.EventsID) AS Maximum
FROM Players pl
LEFT JOIN Participants pa
    ON pl.PlayersID = pa.PlayersID
GROUP BY
    pl.PlayersID
ORDER BY
    MAX(pa.EventsID) DESC;
```

If you want to cater for the possibility of two players being tied for the same maximum, then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` instead of just `TOP 1`.